# Facing issue in Overriding synapse template parameters in three different Azure devops branches?As templates are store in workspace_publish

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics, azure-synapse-pipeline

I have three different branches in Azuredevops and my synapse templates are stored in workspace_publish branch,I need to overwrite these template parameters using Yaml.

- task: Synapse workspace deployment@1
  inputs:
  TemplateFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(SourceWorkspaceName)/TemplateForWorkspace.json'
  ParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(SourceWorkspaceName)/TemplateParametersForWorkspace.json'
  azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
  ResourceGroupName: '$(DeploymentResourceGroupName)'
  TargetWorkspaceName: '$(DeployWorkspaceName)'
  DeleteArtifactsNotInTemplate: true
  OverrideArmParameters: |
  workspaceName: $(DeployWorkspaceName)
  # :  there are parameters in arm template
  # : 
  Environment: 'prod'

I don't have Template file in my current branch.Could someone help me how to export those files using Yaml file?

I tried reading template file directly from workspace_publish branch but didn't worked out.